# Border Radius & Glowing Links

Tags: hyperlink, css

I Google searched the code for border radius & glowing buttons. When I got the code I replaced input with a. Here is the code:

```
a {
    border:2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px; 
}

a:focus { 
    outline:none;
    border-color:#9ecaed;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

How do I make a link round and make it glow when hover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the pseudo class `:hover` instead of `:focus`?

```
a:hover{
  /* glow code */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only cross-platform solution I've been able to use successfully so far is: [jQuery Glow](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-glow).